# three.js postprocessing without affecting scene background

Tags: three.js, post-processing

I feel like I'm overthinking this.

How can I apply postprocessing effects to my three.js scene without affecting the scene background texture?

For context, I am building a WebAR experience with 8th Wall. I can render the camera texture behind the three.js scene by setting `scene.background = camTexture` but when I use `composer.render()` instead of `renderer.render()`, the postprocessing effects are applied to both the three.js scene and to the scene background. I just want to apply the effects to three.js scene and leave the scene background as-is.

Btw, I don't even *need* to set `scene.background = camTexture` unless I am using `EffectComposer()`.  By default the three.js scene has a transparent background and the `cameraTexture` is rendered behind the three.js scene. But the minute I use `EffectComposer`, it shows a solid white background instead of staying transparent, which is why I set `scene.background = camTexture`.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions!